# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I get this error when I try to use this code in Unity(Visual Studio) for a UWP:

```cs
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writetext = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "/data.json"))
{
    writetext.WriteLine(datastring);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `StorageFile` Approach. See [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)